# Persistant vim-like Registers in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, vim, firefox-extensions

Is there an add-on for Firefox that supports the use of vim-like persistent registers when editing textboxes and text areas?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Great idea! Would you mind if I implement this as a chrome plugin?